# Async CTP NullReference or ArgumentNullException (Windows Phone)

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, nullreferenceexception, async-ctp

I have problem with using Async CTP library in my project.
Here is code:

BookPage

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        if (this.DataContext is BookViewModel)
        {
            var bookViewModel = this.DataContext as BookViewModel;
            bookViewModel.UpdateReviews();
        }
    }
```

BookViewModel

```
public async void UpdateReviews()
    {
        Reviews.Clear();

        IEnumerable<Review> newReviews = null;
        try
        {
            newReviews = await BooksManager.GetBookReviews(this.Book.Sysno, 10, 0);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        if (newReviews != null)
        {
            foreach (var review in newReviews)
            {
                Reviews.Add(review);
            }
        }
    }
```

BooksManager

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<Review>> GetBookReviews(string sysno, uint limit, uint offset)
    {
        if (sysno == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("sysno");
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sysno))
            throw new ArgumentException("sysno");

        string url = CreateBookReviewsURL(sysno, limit, offset);

        var reviews = await DownloadDataAsync<IEnumerable<Review>>(url);
        return reviews;
    }

public static async Task<T> DownloadDataAsync<T>(string url)
    {
        if (url == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("url");

        var newUrl = url.Contains("?") ? 
            string.Format("{0}d={1}", url, DateTime.Now) :
             string.Format("{0}?d={1}", url, DateTime.Now); //to avoid caching

        string data = null;

        WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(newUrl);

        using (WebResponse response = await webRequest.GetResponseAsync())
        {

            if (response.Headers["StatusCode"] == "200")
            {
                using (var stm = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stm))
                    {
                        data = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var books = await ParseDataAsync<T>(data);
        return books;
    }
```

It throws  NullReferenceException

> at
>   SmartLib.ViewModels.BooksViewModel.d_*8.MoveNext()
>
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.<>c*_DisplayClass5.b__1(Object
>   state)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo
>   rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object
>   parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly
>   caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj,
>   BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters,
>   CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
>   System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
>   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args)    at
>   System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)    at
>   System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(DispatcherPriority
>   priority)    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(Object
>   context)    at System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(Object[]
>   args)    at
>   System.Windows.Hosting.DelegateWrapper.InternalInvoke(Object[] args)
>   at System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(IntPtr
>   pHandle, Int32 nParamCount, ScriptParam[] pParams, ScriptParam&
>   pResult)

In App.xaml.cs calling BooksManager.GetBookReviews() works correctly.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code? Where exactly does it throw the exception? Which variable is `null`?

Comment: yes, I did. But it is asychronous code and I dont know where exception was thrown.  Is there any way how to debug asynchronous code (maybe some debug options)?

Comment: I think breakpoints should work. So, just put a breakpoint after the `await`.